# Cordova/iOS Capabilities

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, cordova

I tried searching for answers to my questions but I was unable to find any. I want to develop a native `iOS` application using `cordova` and I was wondering if it was possible to:

1. Create a custom login page and then point to a url in the org (ex. /apex/myPage) using the custom login credentials
2. Is it possible to maintain login state? Meaning, can a user log in, completely close the app, and then open it back up while still being logged in?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could build a custom hybrid application using SDK .The salesforce login page can have different logo needed and different images if you use my domain and create your own domain .Also the hybrid app you can configure to be of server driven where you can define your home page to be /apex/vf page .The session management will be automatically taken care by SDK

Comment: **Native** and **Cordova** are also mutually exclusive. Cordova will create for you a webview-in-a-box, a.k.a. a "hybrid" application, that is far from native. I believe Cordova has a bare minimum of local storage to allow the login state refresh you describe.